# Get Google Maps place name from latitude & longitude

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using the Google API (Javascript v3) and need to be able to convert latitude and longitude to a place name (not an address), and visa versa. I have read a lot of articles saying to use the Reverse Geocoding to get this but so far I have only been able to get the **formatted_address** and not the actual **place name**.

The code I was using for this is:

```
function showLocationAddress(e) {
var latlng = { lat: e.latLng.lat(), lng: e.latLng.lng() };
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;

 geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    $('#location').empty();
    $('#location').val(results[0].formatted_address);
  } else {
   window.alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
  }
 });
}
```

Currently the user can use the autosearch function which within a text field on the map and I can get the place_id, address, and lat and long (as discribed in [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder) link). This is instantiated by calling `var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);` and the place details are then retrieved using `place = autocomplete.getPlace();`.

The difficulty I am having is that I also need the same information (place_id, address, and lat and long) to be available when the user clicks on the map, but as I am not using the Autocomplete text field I don't know how to do this.

I thought it would have been something like `var place = new google.maps.places.Place(latLng);`.

Comment: Look at the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) NearbySearch.